# Force .htaccess RewriteRules to ignore certain folders?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

How can I rewrite this rule below so that it ignores certain folders and all of the content inside those folders.

```
# BEGIN WishList Member Attachment Protection
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfile=$1 [L]
# END WishList Member Attachment Protection
```

I thought that adding a line like above the current rewritecond would work but it doesn't appear to be...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldertoignore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldertoignorenumber2
```

Following doesn't work:

```
# BEGIN WishList Member Attachment Protection
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldertoignore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldertoignorenumber2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfile=$1 [L]
# END WishList Member Attachment Protection
```

Comment: @arkascha The rules aren't working when i do it, so something must be wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an error or what do you mean not working?

Comment: @PanamaJack Nope, no error just I can see it's not working. One way I can test is by simply just putting `|css` in the rewritecond line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it's not working. However you should be able to do you rules this way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder1|folder2)/?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfile=$1 [L]
```

You can also try the rules this way. If it matches those directories do nothing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2)/?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfile=$1 [L]
```

Also be sure to clear browser cache just in case.

Comment: Your first option worked, it was the `/?(.*)` part that fixed it.